# Is there any operator for the scattering problem of an elastic wave in Hilbert space?

Tags: waves, hilbert-space, operators, scattering

From an algebraic perspective, there is a common shape for wave propagation that includes operators in Hilbert space. I want to know is there any operator in Hilbert space that describes the elastic wave scattering problem?

Comment: You should look up the S-Matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix

Comment: Dear @DavideMorgante I read that page but it's not about my question. Search on the net for the article with the same concept as your mention and find something but its hard for me to find the whole of the topic. I think the math of the article out of my knowledge.
https://asa.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1121/1.381129